How to identify the best use of the logit link function in regression?
I am confused about how to identify the best use of the logit link function in regression problems.
Here is my current understanding of the topic. My confusion stems from the fact that for continuous data between $0$ and $1$, both Case 2 and Case 3 seem applicable.

Case 1: Logit Link Function for Binary Response Data (Data is either $0$ or $1$).
While this is not directly applicable to my problem, this seems to be the most common use of the logit link. We assume that each $y_i$ is Bernoulli:
$$ Y_i \sim \text{Bernoulli}(\mu_i) $$
Here, $\mu_i$ represents both the probability of success and the expected value:
$$ E(Y_i) = \mu_i $$
$$ \text{Var}(Y_i) = \mu_i(1-\mu_i) $$
The probability mass function can be written in terms of $\mu_i$:
$$ P(Y_i = y_i) = \mu_i^{y_i}(1-\mu_i)^{1-y_i}, \quad y_i \in \{0,1\} $$
Using regular GLM notation, we can write:
$$ \eta_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{i1} + \beta_2X_{i2} + ... + \beta_pX_{ip} $$
$$ g(\mu_i) = \log\left(\frac{\mu_i}{1-\mu_i}\right) = \eta_i $$
$$ \mu_i = g^{-1}(\eta_i) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\eta_i}} $$
$$ L(\beta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \mu_i^{y_i}(1-\mu_i)^{1-y_i} $$
$$ E(Y_i|X_i) = \mu_i = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_{i1} + ... + \beta_pX_{ip})}} $$

Case 2: Logit Link Function for Proportion Response Data (Data is between $0$ and $1$)
This time, we can represent each observation $Y_i$ as a  proportion $\frac{m_i}{n_i}$ where $m_i$ is the number of successes out of $n_i$ trials and use the binomial distribution:
$$ Y_i \sim \text{Binomial}(n_i, \mu_i) $$
Here, $\mu_i$ still represents the probability of success for each trial and:
$$ E(Y_i) = n_i\mu_i $$
$$\text{Var}(Y_i) = n_i\mu_i(1-\mu_i)$$
The probability mass function becomes:
$$ P(Y_i = y_i) = \binom{n_i}{y_i}\mu_i^{y_i}(1-\mu_i)^{n_i-y_i}, \quad y_i \in \{0,1,...,n_i\} $$
Using the GLM framework, we maintain the same structure:
$$ \eta_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{i1} + \beta_2X_{i2} + ... + \beta_pX_{ip} $$
$$ g(\mu_i) = \log\left(\frac{\mu_i}{1-\mu_i}\right) = \eta_i $$
$$ \mu_i = g^{-1}(\eta_i) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\eta_i}} $$
$$ L(\beta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \binom{n_i}{y_i}\mu_i^{y_i}(1-\mu_i)^{n_i-y_i} $$
$$ E(Y_i|X_i) = n_i\mu_i = \frac{n_i}{1 + e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_{i1} + ... + \beta_pX_{ip})}} $$

Case 3: Logit Link Function for Continuous Proportion Data via the Beta Distribution (Data is between $0$ and $1$)
This time, it seems that we are directly modelling the response. For each observation $Y_i$, we write:
$$ Y_i \sim \text{Beta}(\alpha_i, \beta_i) $$
We reparametrize the Beta distribution using mean ($\mu_i$) and precision ($\phi$) parameters instead of $\alpha_i$ and $\beta_i$:
$$ \alpha_i = \mu_i\phi $$
$$ \beta_i = (1-\mu_i)\phi $$
Under this parameterization:
$$ E(Y_i) = \mu_i $$
$$ \text{Var}(Y_i) = \frac{\mu_i(1-\mu_i)}{1+\phi} $$
The probability density function becomes:
$$ f(y_i|\mu_i,\phi) = \frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma(\mu_i\phi)\Gamma((1-\mu_i)\phi)}y_i^{\mu_i\phi-1}(1-y_i)^{(1-\mu_i)\phi-1} $$
Using the GLM framework:
$$ \eta_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_{i1} + \beta_2X_{i2} + ... + \beta_pX_{ip} $$
Again we use the logit link:
$$ g(\mu_i) = \log\left(\frac{\mu_i}{1-\mu_i}\right) = \eta_i $$
$$ \mu_i = g^{-1}(\eta_i) = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-\eta_i}} $$
The likelihood and conditional expectation become:
$$ L(\beta,\phi) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{\Gamma(\phi)}{\Gamma(\mu_i\phi)\Gamma((1-\mu_i)\phi)}y_i^{\mu_i\phi-1}(1-y_i)^{(1-\mu_i)\phi-1} $$
$$ E(Y_i|X_i) = \mu_i = \frac{1}{1 + e^{-(\beta_0 + \beta_1X_{i1} + ... + \beta_pX_{ip})}} $$

Thus, to me it seems that this categorization is the best way to use the logit link function:

If you observe data where the underlying data generation process for the response is directly $0$ or $1$ : Use the set up in Case 1
If you observe data where the underlying data generation process for the response is a trial and we are interested in the success rate : Use the set up in Case 2
If you observe data where the underlying data generation process for the response is directly a continuous number between 0,1 : Use the set up in Case 3

This categorization seems to be the most natural way to handle the true nature of the data without shoehorning an approach to a situation where it does not fit. Is this categorization correct?

The question seems kind of inside out; usually we have data and ideas and then have to decide how to analyze it.  Sometimes that will be logit, sometimes something else. So, I'm confused as to what exactly you are asking.
